# How can I view a list of syntax errors in a script without running the script on the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2008

Simple question:

Does running Debug in SSMS actually execute the script on the server?

How can I view a list of syntax errors in a script without running the script on the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Where else would it execute it?

Comment: Simple answer: Yes, of course.

Comment: Let me rephrase this... how can I view a list of syntax errors in a script without running the script on the database?

Comment: `Query -> Parse` (blue checkmark icon) - this will check the syntax and tell you if the query parses.

Comment: @Oded Perfect, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Just one final question, what's the point in the Debug if it's going to run buggy code on a database?

Comment: So you can debug through your SQL (doesn't _have_ to be buggy, you know)? What's the point of Debug in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Query -> Parse` (also the blue checkmark icon).

From MSDN - [Database Engine Query Editor (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177264.aspx):

> Parse - Check the syntax of the selected code. If no code is selected, checks the syntax of the all code in the Query Editor window.